# Insert blank value

Tags: regex

I'm trying to insert blank into my replace function however, the tool I am using does not allow me to leave the box empty, states I must enter a value - see image.

[image: find and replace box]

My find function is removing everything from a hyphen symbol onwards. Is there a value I could enter into the replace box that inserts nothing?

For some reason this box will not let me leave it empty.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: As a workaround you can try adding `(.)` to the start of your regex (which will capture any character) and then replace with the value of the captured group.

Comment: Use (.)?? in the start of your regex. That won't match anything, but you can still replace with Group 1.

Comment: `^|.+$` that match witheverything

Comment: Does that tool even support groups? I'd say it's a bug that the field is required. Until it is fixed you could try to just remove the constraint in the html source code and see if the server accepts it.

Comment: `\-().+$` replaced by `$1` (group 1) could work, but only if substitution with groups are supported. Note that the group is simply empty and therefore the substitution will be empty as well.

Comment: Thanks for all the input guys - will try and feedback, currently waiting for the tool to update, its quite slow

Comment: If I assume it's not a bug, then it might make sense as a feature if a "delete(pattern)" function exists in addition to the "replace(pattern, replacement)" function.

Comment: Groups won't help to insert a space if the group does not match a space. If there is no space in the input, it won't be possible to insert it with a backreference. There *must* be a way to specify space in the replacement pattern. Please consult your tool docs.

Comment: Did you solve the issue?